# EventSource and buffered HttpResponse

Tags: dart

I am trying to use EventSource on the client side and
one the server side I am using HttpRequest.response
which returns an object of type HttpResponse.

I am using HttpResponse.write to write events back
to the client side but it seems that these events
are only actually written (i.e., flushed) when the
HttpResponse object is closed, which implies also
closing the client-server communication server.
This kind of defeats the purpose of using EventSource.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Dart's HttpResponse. I will file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to be looking at if you want to keep the connection between client and server alive between requests is called WebSockets.

See this tutorial for examples: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch05.html

Comment: Websockets are not replacement for EventSource. Dart's HttpResponse for some reason buffers the written bytes even when buffering is disabled. Websockets don't work everywhere (example behind a corporate proxy/firewall). Also not everyone needs Websocket's bidirectional communication. EventSource is simple  for unidirectional communication that works every where.

I will file issue for this.